# Subtract V1 and V0 from other visit values in long format using grouping

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset in long format and I am want to create two variables, one where visit=1 value for a given ID is subtracted from all other values and one where visit=0 value for a given ID is subtracted from all other values. Sample dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(value=rnorm(30), 
               visit=rep(seq(0:9), 3), i
               d=c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10)))
```

I know one method is to use the following code:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
       arrange(visit, .by_group=TRUE) %>%
       mutate(value_chg_v1=value-nth(value, n=2),
              value_chg_v0=value-nth(value, n=1))
```

but I want to construct the code so that if a entire row is missing for visit=0, value_chg_v0=NA. Is there a way to do this that does not involve adding in the rows where visit=0 is missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `rep(seq(0:9), 3)` gives different values than you intended.  Also, when you say `nth`, it doesn't differentiate whether the 'visit' starts from 0 or 2 or 5

Answer (score 1):

We could use `complete` to create the missing combinations

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   complete(id, visit = 0:9) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(visit, .by_group=TRUE) %>%
   mutate(value_chg_v1=value-nth(value, n=2),
          value_chg_v0=value-nth(value, n=1)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   drop_na(value)
```

Comment: akrun that does work with a couple modifications:                                   
 `                                                                                                            
 df %>% 
   complete(id, visit = 0:9, fill = list(value = NA)) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(visit, .by_group=TRUE) %>%
   mutate(value_chg_v1=value-nth(value, n=2),
          value_chg_v0=value-nth(value, n=1)) %>%                                                                        
   drop_na(value) `

Comment: @gecko what modifications you need in the output

Comment: @gecko the reason i changed to `fill = list(value = 0))` from the default NA with `complete` is that when you do the `value-nth(value, n=1)` it returns NA as the first value is NA and any arithmetic with NA returns NA

Comment: @gecko if you need to remove the `NA`, then it is fiine, I can use the default option which returns NA for value column